# Custom CursorAdapater's bindView called 77 times...have I done something wrong?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297323/custom-cursor-adapter-calling-bindview-multiple-times) where it says not to worry about it but I guess I need some reassurance.

My custom CursorAdapter's bindView:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
    // get handles for views in xml
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.add_lvrow_image);
    TextView titleView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.add_lvrow_title);

    // get data from cursor and "massage" if necessary
    String imageUri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CollectionsTable.COL_IMAGEURI));
    String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CollectionsTable.COL_TITLE));

    // terrible time getting run-time sizes of imageView, hardcode for now
    int XML_WIDTH = 100;
    int XML_HEIGHT = 100;       

    Log.d(TAG, SCOPE + "bindView called: " +count);
    count++;

    // use static util class
    ImageUtils.loadBitmap(context, imageUri, imageView, XML_WIDTH, XML_HEIGHT);
```

I'm following the [series of Android tutorials for loading large bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) but have moved `decodSmapledBitmapFromUri`, `calculateInSmapleSize`, `loadBitmap`, `BitmapWorkerTask`, `AsyncDrawable`, `cancelPotentialWork`, and `getBitmapWorkerTask` to a utility folder.

...so I'm calling `loadBitmap` and it's chain 77 times for a listview that currently has 12 rows in it (six show on the screen at load time with just a hint of the 7th showing).

So I shouldn't worry, this is okay (this number of calls to bindView & the firing off of all those subsequent methods)?

Thanks for your words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If in your listview xml android:layout_height is not "match_parent" change it to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: Thank you for your words. I had the listview fragment with a height of `wrap content` sitting inside a `Framelayout` that was also `wrap content`, I changed both of those to `match parent` and the calls to bind view shot down to 7, as I originally would have wished. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The `newView` method is called for each newly created view while the `bindView` is called once each view data is required to bind to the corresponding view. One of the reasons that cause `bindView` get called several times is listview recycling which recycles the views that goes out of viewport. As an example when you scroll over a listview every new view which comes to view port would cause a call to `bindView`. I suggest you to create a cache mechanism if your `loadBitmap` is resource intensive so that you shouldn't have a new call to `loadBitmap` for each `bindView` call.

Comment: Thank you for your words. I used, per the tutorial mentioned in OP, a LruCache but that is built and maintained distal to `loadBitmap`; but your words have me thinking maybe there should be a cache prior to the  `loadBitma` call; unfortunately I'm not very savvy with caches (actually the LruCache is the first one I ever implemented). Ultimately altering the XML fixed the problem but I'll keep your cache suggestion in mind. Thank you for your energy in helping me fix my woes.